# How to change alt + ctrl + delete menu for a specific user Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, user, ctrl-alt-delete

I have found a way to change the alt + ctrl + delete menu for all users in Windows 10. Is there a way to change it for a specific user?

Comment: What have you tried? Change it in what way?

Comment: You might be able to do it in the registry under the current user key....https://www.thewindowsclub.com/change-ctrl-alt-delete-options-windows

Comment: To use the method in the link by @Moab, you need to be logged-in as that user. The user can himself modify it back, if he is sophisticated enough.

Comment: @Moab - your solution sounds good, but I can only navigate as far as the policies folder under the current user. There's is no system folder. Do I create one using "Key"?

Comment: @Moab - your solution sounds works. but I can only run regedit as the admin, and then it changes it for the admin user, not the visitor.

Comment: @Moab - I can set the group policy (gpedit.msc) for all users then use your technique to override for the current user. Thanks!

Comment: @JackBeNimble You can answer your own question if you wish, since you figured it out with a little help.